# How can I have a UserControl that contains Buttons on an ItemsControl that control UserControls that are inside of the ItemsControl (Wizard) in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, itemscontrol, wizard

Fairly new to WPF and I am wanting to create a Wizard.

So I have a UserControl called WizardUC.xaml that contains:

```
namespace ClientApplication.View.Wizard
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for WizardUC.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class WizardUC : ItemsControl
    {
        public WizardUC()

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    List<UserControl> userControls = new List<UserControl>();
    int currentUserControl = 0;

    private void ItemsControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (UserControl i in Items)
        {
            userControls.Add(i);
            i.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        userControls[currentUserControl].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

And a Window called WizardTest.xaml that contains:

```
<Window x:Class="ClientApplication.View.TestViews.WizardTest"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="WizardTest" Height="358" Width="351" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:ClientApplication.View.Wizard" xmlns:my1="clr-namespace:ClientApplication.View.Ribbon.CalendarUsercontorls" xmlns:my2="clr-namespace:ClientApplication.View.Ribbon">

    <Grid>
        <my:WizardUC Height="261" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="wizardUC1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="278">
            <my1:DetailToDo HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
           <my2:UserControlSchadule HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </my:WizardUC>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So as you can see I have added two UserControls into the WizardUC.

Essentially what I am wanting is to have Buttons to control Back and Next etc on a Usercontrol that's on the ItemsControl.

Any help will be appreciated! :)

Comment: Personally I would take a slightly different approach. I would create a `CurrentUserControl` property which returns `UserControls[CurrentIndex]`, and bind it to a `<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentUserControl}" />`, then I would have my Back/Next buttons simply change the `CurrentIndex` property, which would raise a PropertyChange notification which would trigger the change notification for the `CurrentUserControl`. Very similar to how I like to setup [navigation with MVVM](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/), but on a smaller scale.

Comment: Sounds like a much easier approach. I'll give it a shot after work and let you know how it goes :) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I implemented that in and changed it from an itemscontrol back to a usercontrol. Things are looking bright and dandy from here. Thanks a lot :)